# How to handle pull request when its base is another branch that hasn't been merged?

Tags: git, github

Situation is as follows:

- First bug was fixed on BranchA
- BranchA was pushed and a pull request was made to original repo
- Second bug fix relayed on the first fix so BranchB (containing the second bug fix) was build on top of BranchA
- BranchB was pushed and a pull request was made to original repo

My question can be divided in these two parts:

- How the original repo should handle this situation as the commits given on BranchB (and therefore the second PR) includes all the commits on the first PR (BranchA)?
- Can first PR and second PR get safely merged without any issue as long as first PR gets merged first?

[image: Graphical Situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is **two ways** to manage this situations :

- Close the first PR (Branch A) and merge the second one (Branch B)
- Merge the first PR (Branch A) and after this, merge the second one (Branch B)

First option :

[image: First option graphical explanations]

Second option :

[image: Second option graphical expl]

Concerning your second question, yes it'll be safely merge, if there is no conflict.

Comment: What would be the graphical scenario for the second bullet?

Comment: In this case, it's cool because your branch B is coming from the Branch A, so commits are already in there (in B).